# Run tasks in different hours

Tags: php, cron

I have a list of +20 tasks to run. My problem is that I can't run them all at once, and I dont know how many tasks to run every day (it can change).

So here is what I'm doing :

1. I have a cron that run every days
2. This cron runs an SQL command to get a list of tasks to process
3. If my list of tasks is smaller than my processor count, I run all the tasks with PHP using exec($command)
4. If not (and here is my problem), I would like to split my list into chunks, and run the first subset, and plan the other subsets one our 2 hours later

## update

Thanks to @jasonK contribution, I have a starting point to my problem : [**Using at**](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm)

So I created a php file test.php :

```
<?php
    $f = fopen("hello.txt", "a");
    fwrite($f, date("Y-m-d :H:i:s")."\n");
    fclose($f);
?>
```

When I run in shell `php test.php | at now + 2 minutes` this prompt me this message `job 4 at Sat May  5 07:24:00 2018`
but I see that the file has been updated without waiting 2 minutes ! in other words, the script is executed immediatly even if the message prompted is good.

Any Idea ?

Comment: You could use the at command to have it run in two hours. https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm

Comment: hey @JasonK yes it's what I need, but you can run it only manually because of a prompt and Conrol+D to exit... is there something that can be run by a script like `exec($cmd, "at now+2hours")`?

Comment: Can't you just split the other results and update the DB so the record reflects when they should be updated?

Comment: Just fork it off and sleep for 2 hours, can do this both in bash and php.

Comment: You can pass it in with echo.  echo "echo 'Test out' > ~/test.txt" |at now

Comment: both updating db and sleeping several hours are not good "options" for me. thanks for your contributions :)

Comment: @JasonK I think your method is definitely the good approach. updated my post with your comments but still have a problem

Comment: Need to do: echo "php test.php" | at now + 2 minutes

Comment: With out the echo it's just running the test.php and sending that output to the at command.

Comment: nope, doesn't work even with echo. this is not producing anything

Comment: Probably need the full path to your program. The at command has no idea where the test.php is. echo "php fullPath/test.php" | at now + 2 minutes

Comment: I set the full path in the command line and in the php file, but doesn't work. it prompt me that the job is scheduled in 1 minute, but the file is not updated

Comment: In the php you need the full path to the file. You will need a+ to create the file.

Comment: I have the fullpath and the file already exists. have you tried the command ? does it work for you ?

Comment: Works for me no problem. Not sure what is going on. I'm assuming you are file that you know you can write too.

Comment: @JasonK OK, it was a problem with Mac OS, I tried the same script on Ubuntu and it works fine ! thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by doing this :

```
echo "php test.php" | at now + X minutes|hours
```

This is not working on Mac os, but works like a charm on Ubuntu.

Many thanks to @JasonK who pointed me to the solution.